# Highcharts Weird Behavior on Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to render some simple charts, i use Highchart Stock to use the  scrollbar function due by the large amount of data that i'm supose to print. So i have a table who renders the chart and gets the data by some module who filters what data is going to show.

I got this weird behavior, where the scrollbar can't set the extremes Min and Max, ¿When happens?
The rendered Chart has 15 ~ bars of data,  (we are using Chart.type `bar` ) we limit the extremes setting it like this

```
chart.xAxis[0].update(
    {
      min: 0
      max: 9 
    }
)
```

And the we just `redraw()` the chart. so there's  5 bars that doesn't shows because the limits we put and that's right. the issue occurs following the next steps.

Having the 15 bars of data,  scroll down to the last bar then update the chart with new data but
less amount of it:  5 ~ bars, the chart keeps the scroll where the last index of the bar was, and not reseting the view where it should be. in this case we `set` the `Extremes` everytime the amount of bars or data is below 10~, so it supose to view only 5 bars in the chart but it shows all lastest index of data showed before. now if you render from the low amount of data to a new filter of them and is larger than the last one, it keeps the lastest update of max view and min view, so it will show 5 bars even if there is 13 bars. (updating the parameters doesn't even work)

Theres a demo where you can reproduce my problem.
[Highcharts ScrollBar Issue](https://jsfiddle.net/LancelotVR/hcj8q1st/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you redraw your chart after each operation - it is enough to redraw only once. To get rid of the main issue use `setExtremes` instead of `update` method.

```
  HC.addSeries({
    data: Data
  }, false);

  let MaxViewItems = 0;

  if (RandyIndex > 10) {
    MaxViewItems = 10;
  } else if (RandyIndex <= 10) {
    MaxViewItems = RandyIndex;
  }

  HC.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, MaxViewItems - 1, false);

  HC.redraw();
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zmfLrp6y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Thank you so much, this solves my problem.  moving to redrawing the chart each operation, ¿are you meaning it to having inside the click event or due the `update` function that i was trying to use?

Comment: Hi @lancelotvr, I am glad that I could help. I mean to set the `redraw` argument in `addSeries` and `setExtremes` to false.